# Which is better practice? Querying Server via VBA/SQL Command Text or VBA/Stored Procedure?

Tags: sql, excel, vba, t-sql

We need to query data from SQL Server using an OLEDB connection from an Excel workbook. We have discovered that there are 2 ways to do this. In terms of security, maintenance, performance, daily use, end-user use, etc., do you think one has an overall advantage over the other?

1. VBA script to string parameters to define the SQL command text via Connections in Excel:

   ```
   Sub ParamPass()
       Dim qPreText As String
       Dim qPostText As String
       Dim valueToFilter As String
       Dim paramPosition As Integer
       valueToFilter = "TableName.ColumnName ="

   With
       ActiveWorkbook.Connections("ConnectionName").OLEDBConnection
       qPreText = .CommandText
       paramPosition = InStr(qPreText, valueToFilter) + Len(valueToFilter)-1
       qPreText = Left(qPreText, paramPosition)
       qPostText = .CommandText
       qPostText = Right(qPostText, Len(qPostText) - paramPosition)
       qPostText = Right(qPostText, Len(qPostText) - InStr(qPostText, ")") + 1)
       .CommandText = qPreText & " '" & Sheets("SheetName").Range("CellReference").Value & "'" & qPostText
   End With

   ActiveWorkbook.Connections("ConnectionName").Refresh

   End Sub
   ```
2. VBA script to call and pass parameters to a stored procedure in the database:

   ```
   Sub ParamPass()
       Dim MyValueToPass As String
       MyValueToPass = Sheets("SheetName").Range("CellReference").Value

   With
       ActiveWorkbook.Connections("ConnectionName").OLEDBConnection
       .CommandText = "exec dbo.StoredProcName '" & MyValueToPass & "'"
       ActiveWorkbook.Connections("ConnectionName").Refresh
   End With

   End Sub
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer the second method due to its simplicity.

The issue here is mainly defense against SQL Injection Attacks. In both solutions you are using String parameters. An user could enter "= 1; Drop YourTable;"

Im not too privy with VBA but I know in Java has "Prepared Statement" command which takes care of this. You should do some research on this for VBA SQL.

Here is a good article on it. http://bytes.com/topic/access/insights/864109-sql-injection-attack

Comment: Thanks for the input, Dasman, I'll take a look at the article you shared now.